# chainerを使った画像認識でAttributeError

Tags: python, python3, chainer

初心者です。
pythonの画像認識をしてみたいと思い[こちら](http://karaage.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2016/07/08/073000)の記事に沿って進めていましたが、chainer 公式リポジトリの[このコード](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/4f0073f70f2d4a044b382214cf1ea592654d1f04/examples/modelzoo/evaluate_caffe_net.py)を実行しようとして

```sh
$ python evaluate_caffe_net.py test.txt caffenet bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel -b ./ -B 1
```

で

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate_caffe_net.py", line 46, in <module>
    chainer.config.train = False  # All the codes will run in test mode
AttributeError: module 'chainer' has no attribute 'config'
```

というエラーが出てしまいました。
本来なら記事のように、

```
Loading Caffe model file bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel...
Loaded
mean loss:     8.06329917908
mean accuracy: 0.0
```

というように出力されるようです。
AttributeErrorについて色々調べてみたりコードも読んでみましたが解決しません。何か考えられる原因があれば試してみたいので、思いつく問題点を教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

OSはmacOS HighSierra 10.13.2
Anacondaを使用してPythonのバージョンを3.6.3に切り替えていました。
Chainerのバージョンは1.8.1です。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　環境の情報（OSの種類、chainerのバージョン、Anaconda を使っているか、など）を追記してくださいませんか。質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できます。

Comment: 特に `chainer.config.train` は Chainer バージョン 2 からの機能であり、今回これが見つからないとエラーが出ているので、Chainer のバージョンが重要そうに思います。 https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade.html#global-configurations

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん
コメント・編集ありがとうございます。Chainerのバージョンを変えて試してみます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん   
`pip install chainer==2.0.0`し直したところ解決致しました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chainer.config.train` は Chainer [バージョン 2 からの機能であり](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade.html#global-configurations)、今回これが見つからないとエラーが出ています。このため、Chainer のバージョンを確認してください。

現在インストールされているバージョンの確認は、Chainer を Anaconda 経由でインストールした場合
 `conda list | grep chainer` で可能です。また、pip 経由でインストールした場合 `pip show chainer` で可能です。

Chainer のアップグレードは、Anaconda を使うのでしたら `conda install -c anaconda chainer`、素の pip を使うのでしたら `pip install 'chainer>=2.0.0'` で可能です。